# How to display a CSS drop-down menu in a parent with limited width?

Tags: javascript, css, greasemonkey

I'm tweaking SE's web UI with a Greasemonkey script in Firefox 46.0.1 but I'm stuck at the following issue.

My `.css` contains the following for drop-down menus:

```css
/* From: http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp */

/* Dropdown button on hover & focus */
/*.igb-button:hover, .igb-button:focus {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
    }
*/

/* The container - needed to position the dropdown content */
.igb-dropdown-container {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    }

/* Change the colors of the dropdown button on hover */
.igb-dropdown-container:hover {
    background-color: #07c;
    color: white;
    }

/* Show the dropdown content on hover */
.igb-dropdown-container:hover .igb-dropdown-content {
    display: block;
    }

/* Dropdown content (hidden by default) */
.igb-dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: -7em;
    /*background-color: #f9f9f9;*/
    min-width: 16em;
    box-shadow: 12px 12px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 9999;
    }

/* Links inside the dropdown content */
.igb-dropdown-content a {
    color: DarkSlateGray;
    padding: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    }

/* Change color of dropdown content links on hover */
.igb-dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #07c;
    color: white;
    }
```

I add the menus with the following code:

```
for ( let tag of tags ) {

    ...

    let dropdown = $('<span>')
        .attr('id', 'igb-dropdown-content')
        .addClass('igb-dropdown-content')
        //.insertAfter($('#content'))  // inserted here as sibling of 'content',
        //.offset($(tag).offset())     // since 'sidebar' is to small to display menus properly

    $('<span>')  // Why is this not focusable, even if it is an '<a>'?
        .attr('id', 'igb-dropdown-container')
        .addClass('igb-dropdown-container')
        .append( $('<a>')
            .text("▼")
            .addClass('igb-button')
            )
        .insertAfter(tag)
        .append(dropdown)  // inserted above as sibling of 'content', 
                             // since 'sidebar' is to small to display menus properly

    ...

    }
```

This works but looks like the following:

[image: OK]
[image: Not OK]

To get rid of the parent's (`sidebar`) width limitation I had the idea to put them a level higher in the DOM and use offset positioning. Hence, I refactored the above code as mentioned in the line comments, i.e. I flipped the code comments. The result is that none of the menus is shown when hovering over `▼`.

I checked the DOM with Firebug and all the menus are there at the intented place (siblings of `content`). If I disable `display:none;` in `.igb-dropdown-content` all menus are shown. But all of them stay grayed out when hovering over `▼`.

P.S.: The question in the code concerning focusing still puzzles me, too.

**UPDATE:** I put a minimal working example on https://jsfiddle.net/2hd9j4ms/

Comment: Is there any way you can put this all up on http://jsfiddle.net? It simply makes it easier for the readers to help you find a solution.